# Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use

Tags: typescript

```js
const useSetState = <T extends object>(
  initialState: T = {} as T
): [T, (patch: Partial<T> | ((prevState: T) => Partial<T>)) => void] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(initialState);
  const setMergeState = useCallback(
    (patch) => {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        ...(patch instanceof Function ? patch(prevState) : patch),
      }));
    },
    [setState]
  );

  return [state, setMergeState];
};
```

But I found this error: Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)).

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? Please see [ask].

Comment: It's saying to not use the object type, because [almost] everything is an object. You have to type it differently

Answer (score 4):

The object type is almost deprecated since everything is an object. For object, use `{}` type, it will allow any properties. For everything, use `any`. But everything is an object, so the main any property (the type of everything) doesn't make sense. So TypeScript now uses to turn off type checking. Don't use it.

So everything is an object, don't use `extends object`. Use only `T`.

---

Why **everything is an object**? JavaScript (so TypeScript too) always has been an object-oriented programming language. JS is different from Java (for example) because it is prototype-based, C-like is usually class-based. Every value in TS/JS extends from Object class, the same in Java and C#. Any object has properties which value `"string"` has - you can use `"string".toUpperCase()`. Same for numbers, objects of classes (`new XMLHttpReqeust`), static classes (`Math`), literal objects, since without properties (`{}.hasOwnProperty`), arrays and so on...

Comment: If it isn‘t an object, handle it in the function？

Comment: everything is object

Comment: This is not correct. There are primitive types (number, string, null etc.) that are not objects. You can call methods of strings, numbers and boolean because compiler wraps them into objects when it sees that you treat them like objects.

Comment: There is no compiler in JS, probably "interpreter" is the word. Yes, you are right, primitives are not truly objects. While primitives are copied when transfered (for example via parameter), objects transfer its reference (so you can mutate them). But it is not so important here, since primitives are wrapped.