# Typescript Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible

Tags: typescript

I want to convert a generic object of boolean values to a list with all keys, when the value is true. That works quite okay with the following code:

```
  getCharacteristics<T extends object, U extends keyof T>(characteristic: T) {
    return Object.keys(characteristic).filter((key: U) => {
      return characteristic[key]
    })
  }
```

but I get a TypeScript error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => value is string, thisArg?: any): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(key: U) => T[U]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => value is string'.
      Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'U'.
          'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(key: U) => T[U]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown'.
      Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'U'.
          'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
```

without the generic types I get an implicit any warning, so that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second generic parameter (U) is not needed because you can easily set the type of `key` to `keyof T`.

Also, in most use cases [you shouldn't use the `object` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856701/dont-use-object-as-a-type-the-object-type-is-currently-hard-to-use). The `Record<K, V>` (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936369/what-is-the-record-type-in-typescript)) would be more appropriate in most cases.

```js
function getCharacteristics<T extends Record<string, any>>(characteristic: T) {
    return Object.keys(characteristic).filter((key: keyof T) => {
        return characteristic[key];
    });
}
```